# MS SQL DB retrieve two coloumns from one query

Tags: database

I have two tables as below:

1. Students table

   [image: STUDENT TABLE]
2. work table:

   [image: Work table]

My query is:

```
select stud_name
from students
  inner join work on work.library=students.stud_id
where work_id=2
```

It returns name of student correctly. But please tell me is it possible to retrieve two students name via inner join . Example : get RON and JACK name as the out put in a single result set.

I tried:

```
select  stud_name,stud_name
from students
  inner join work on work.library=students.stud_id,work.sports=students.stud_id
where work_id=2
```

But as expected I got a massive error.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @AK_ DBA.SE would have been an option. It is also in scope on Stack Overflow (one of our default migration targets) and this question currently has 3 out of 5 votes to migrate to SO. Please note that a question *shouldn't* be cross posted on multiple sites.

Comment: @MichaelT I'm not a moderator on SE, can't see the Mods votes, and don't care much for how SE is managed. I just directed the OP to a good place to find an answer to his question.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Select a.stud_name, b.stud_name from students a, students b, work w
where w.work_id = 2
and a.stud_id = w.library
and b.stud_id = w.sports
```

The work table is the central part in this and you need the students table twice indepently to get each student.

Comment: While this will work in MSSQL it is no longer recommended to use the old join syntax.  Using `inner join` is the preferred method as `*=` was depricated in 2005 and if memory is serving me right was removed in 2012 (it may be 2014 but it is definitely not there in 2014)